# Access query doesn't allow edits to data

Tags: sql, ms-access, one-to-many

I have a table that tracks communications between a call center and callers.  It has a number of fields and a memo field where notes can be entered.  I also have an automated process which transfers data with the client, and if an address update is made, it adds a communication note stating what the address was, and why it was changed.  The issue I'm having is we get data from two sources, and many times this includes the same people from both sources.  Often times there is only a tiny difference between two addresses (street vs st) and this causes multiple records to be created every month.  The analyst in charge of this client has a query to view records where multiple changes exist (specifically that were created by the automated census) so they can see which are duplicates and which are legit.  I want them to be able to check a box or in some way mark these records to be deleted.

The problem is the resulting query is not editable because the query that helps feed it uses the count function so it isn't necessarily a one-to-one relationship with the table.  Here is the first query:

```
SELECT tblCommunications.RecordID, Count(tblCommunications.RecordID) AS CountOfRecordID
FROM tblCommunications
WHERE (((tblCommunications.CallComments) Like "*Updated address via Census feed.*"))
GROUP BY tblCommunications.RecordID;
```

The second query does a `LEFT JOIN` with this first query and simply displays the table data for those records where `CountofRecordID` is greater than 4.  However, this final listing can not be edited, so the checkbox I added in to mark them for deletion can't be checked.

Does anyone know how I can make this work, or perhaps have a better idea on how to approach this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using aggregate query in `LEFT JOIN`, use it an `IN` clause as `WHERE` condition. Below should then be updateable. Please note query includes table aliases to avoid repeating long table names. Also, a `HAVING` clause is integrated. Adjust as needed.

```
SELECT t.RecordID, t.CallDate, t.Analyst, t.CallComments  
FROM tblCommunications AS t
WHERE t.RecordID ID IN
  (SELECT c.RecordID
   FROM tblCommunications AS c
   WHERE (((c.CallComments) LIKE "*Updated address via Census feed.*"))
   GROUP BY c.RecordID
   HAVING COUNT(c.RecordID) > 4)
```

Comment: I'm trying to get this to work, but not having much luck.  I'm getting the following error: "You have written a subquery that can return more than one field without using the EXISTS reserved word in the main query's FROM clause.  Revise the SELECT statement of the subquery to request only one field."

Comment: This is the query I tried to use:
<pre> <code>    SELECT t.RecordID, t.CallDate, t.Analyst, t.CallComments 
FROM tblCommunications AS t
WHERE t.RecordID IN
  (SELECT c.RecordID, COUNT(c.RecordID) AS CountOfRecordID
   FROM tblCommunications AS c
   WHERE (((c.CallComments) LIKE "*Updated address via Census feed.*"))
   GROUP BY c.RecordID
   HAVING COUNT(c.RecordID) > 4)

Comment: I'm sorry, I tried every variation I could think of based on the help file (https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code) but was unable to get my code to display properly in these comments.

Comment: Actually, I see what is the issue! Remove the `COUNT` aggregate from subquery which is unnecessary. See edit.